# How do I generate the "com.ibm.cloud.iam.Identity.prod" cookie?

Tags: curl, cookies, ibm-cloud, ibm-iam

When logged in to IBM Cloud, you'll get `com.ibm.cloud.iam.Identity.prod` in the cookie.

Using IAM, how do I get this cookie generated? It seems like it is neither `access_token` nor `uaa_token`.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your use case? The authentication for CLI and APIs is well-documented and works.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is technically a `urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:iam-cookie`. You can exchange the cookie for an access token...

`curl -X POST \
  https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic Yng6Yng=' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'grant_type=urn%3Aibm%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Aiam-cookie&response_type=cloud_iam&cookie=xxxxxx'`

Where `xxxxxx` is the cookie.